# Integrate iFlyChat with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a project where my employer wishes me to install a chat plugin into the laravel application I am developing. I am not an expert and I am going through the documentation on the installing it [here](https://iflychat.com/installation/php-chat-client).

Although I haven't tried it yet, I would like to know is this the best way to go about it. Or is there a way I can just pull it via composer and instead of the require statements I could add a provider or alias in the app settings. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iFlyChat is now available via composer - https://packagist.org/packages/iflylabs/iflychat-php. You may directly install it with the help of following command:

```
composer require iflylabs/iflychat-php
```

Answer (score 1):

you can copy "iflychatsettings.php"
, "iflychatuserdetails.php", "iflychat.php" in /app/lib/iflychat-php folder.
and change in composer.json, add /app/lib in classmap after "app/tests/TestCase.php"

in finally run composer update and use it